# How should I educate users about voting?

Tags: discussion

I [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17715925) to a question (nothing big, just a title improvement), and now I got a suggested edit from the OP on my [lowest voted question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17715946) where he asks to upvote this question for him to accept my edit.

Now the procedure would be cleary reject the edit on my question, but I have a strong feeling this user has not understood (fully) why and when up- or downvotes should be applied.

Should I "educate" him how voting works and where to put that (e.g. in a comment on his question)?

EDIT:
Both suggested edits were handled by the reviewers by the time. I understand that the OP or two reviewers can approve an edit.

Comment: I suggest the custom mod flag in such cases. Anyway, there are a number of reviewers to accept/reject edits. Not necessarily dependent on OP

Comment: I'll answer this if you upvote a couple of my answers on the main site. (Seriously though, I left a comment and flagged for mod attention.)

Comment: Oh well.. Looks like OP deleted the question now

Comment: @SurajRao The links to the suggested edits are still working though (at least for me). Am I right that you suggest to flag the question of a user for moderator intervention?

Comment: Yes.. Such cases are best handled by Mods. That kind of quid pro quo is not acceptable in SO. It will be handled now since there already is a flag

Comment: Not related to your question, but if you suggest an edit which fixes mistakes in the title, please consider fixing the same mistakes in the question body, too.

Comment: It's obviously **not** ok to ask for an upvote in return for an upvote or the like but ... Quote: "... feeling this user has not understood (fully) why and when up- or downvotes should be applied" and "Should I educate him how voting works..." Well, if you know how, please educate me too :-) If you browse meta, you'll see that not even high-rep users agree on voting

Comment: Is it me or is the abuse of the voting system becoming endemic? SO many people seem to be trying to manipulate the system (dummy accounts, trying to get people to upvote them in comments, this, etc.) The point of voting is the best questions/answers appear at the top. It seems now people want large rep to put on their CV, etc and they will do virtually anything to achieve that and damn the quality of the site.

Comment: *"How should I educate users about voting?"* - I think the most popular way to do this is to incessantly harass other users - especially new and clueless ones - with requests that they upvote and accept your answers, ideally accompanied with links to Help Center pages about doing so and in as aggrieved and demanding a tone as possible. Using a suggested edit as a medium to suggest a corrupt quid pro quo, while a less popular strategy for providing this vital education, is certainly an innovative one - that user deserves credit for his originality!

Comment: chade_ & @honk In fact, if I were to have reviewed this suggested edit, my action would have been to "Reject and Edit". I would have fixed *all* the issues in the question and left a note in the Edit Summary, where hopefully  the suggester will look, to try and educate them to do the same in future. (Still looking for a better way to do this.)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I'd flag that for a moderator with a custom message explaining why. There really isn't much you can do here, but that IS abuse of the system and a moderator probably wants to know about it so they can talk to the user or take other corrective action if necessary.

As a user it's not your job to directly deal with other users' misbehavior (and this is misbehavior - quid pro quo voting isn't allowed). That's what we have moderators for.

Comment: TIL that every time I have been using quid pro quo in an english context I've meant something completely different than [what I thought it meant](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/55506).

Comment: I broadly agree with the thrust of the answer, but I'd argue that experienced users can _try_ to deal with misbehaviour. They are the initial "carrot", if you like, to the moderator's subsequent "stick". Sometimes merely requesting a change in behaviour, if done politely, can produce the results the community would desire.